# How to load data offline in webview using jsoup in Android?

Tags: android

I need to display only some content on webview so i used jsoup but when trying to cache data jsoup.connect not working without internet.

```
new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Document>() {
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            Document document=null;
            try {
                  document=Jsoup.connect(url).get();
                document.getElementsByClass("footer").remove();
                document.getElementsByClass("navbar").remove();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return document;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document s) {
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(url,s.toString(),"text/html","utf-8","");
            webView.setWebViewClient(new CompletedProjects.MyBrowser());
            webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize( 5 * 1024 * 1024 ); 
            webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath( getActivity().getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath() );
            webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess( true );
            webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled( true );
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled( true );
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT );
            webView.getSettings().setCacheMode( WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK );

            super.onPostExecute(s);
        }
    }.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use WebView for loading sentence like below :

```
   WebView view = new WebView(MainActivity.this);
    view.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    ((LinearLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.text_about)).addView(view);

    view.loadData(getString(R.string.about), "text/html; charset=utf-8", "utf-8");
```

Comment: My question is can we get data cache from Jsoup connect when offline

Comment: dont need of jsop. It can also load data offline.

Comment: I m using jsoup as i need to skip header and footer of website

Comment: Copy your text from website and define that in your string.xml . It will help u to skip header and footer

Comment: <string name="about"><![CDATA[
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:#059bba;background-color:#FFF;">
 </body>
</html>
]]>
</string>

Comment: In between body tag ,write your Sentence